# Submit form via JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Just realized I was going about this all wrong:( I have a bunch of input fields that I want to submit using JQuery .post() or equivelant so I don't navigate away from the page. I have a database driven form that creates a row of multiple inputs using foreach $row and the output looks like this:

```
<tr class="even"><td width=200>Settings</td><input type="hidden" id="Settings[0]"  value="1"><td><input type="textbox" id="Settings[1]" size="75" value="settings.php"></td><td><select id="Settings[2]"><option value="0" selected>No Parent</option><option value="1">Settings</option><option value="2">Grid Demo</option><option value="3">TEST</option><option value="4">Grid Options</option><option value="5">setGridOptions</option><option value="6">Menu Items</option><option value="7">Ajax Menu</option></select></td><td><input type="textbox" id="Settings[3]" size="5" value="0"></td><td><input type="hidden" id="Settings[4]" value="INACTIVE"> <input type="checkbox" id="Settings[4]" value="ACTIVE"></td></tr>
<tr class="odd"><td width=200>Grid Demo</td><input type="hidden" id="Grid_Demo[0]"  value="2"><td><input type="textbox" id="Grid_Demo[1]" size="75" value="grid.php"></td><td><select id="Grid_Demo[2]"><option value="0" selected>No Parent</option><option value="1">Settings</option><option value="2">Grid Demo</option><option value="3">TEST</option><option value="4">Grid Options</option><option value="5">setGridOptions</option><option value="6">Menu Items</option><option value="7">Ajax Menu</option></select></td><td><input type="textbox" id="Grid_Demo[3]" size="5" value="100"></td><td><input type="hidden" id="Grid_Demo[4]" value="INACTIVE"> <input type="checkbox" id="Grid_Demo[4]" value="ACTIVE"></td></tr>
<tr class="even"><td width=200>TEST</td><input type="hidden" id="TEST[0]"  value="3"><td><input type="textbox" id="TEST[1]" size="75" value="test.php"></td><td><select id="TEST[2]"><option value="1">Settings</option><option value="2">Grid Demo</option><option value="3">TEST</option><option value="4">Grid Options</option><option value="5" selected>setGridOptions</option><option value="6">Menu Items</option><option value="7">Ajax Menu</option></select></td><td><input type="textbox" id="TEST[3]" size="5" value="0"></td><td><input type="hidden" id="TEST[4]" value="INACTIVE"> <input type="checkbox" id="TEST[4]" value="ACTIVE"></td></tr>
```

I had been working so hard in php to pull the data into an array and run it through json_encode getting it ready to send to .post() when I realized that it would only continue to save whatever it was when the page was loaded, and not the current state after edits.

Now being so much older and wiser than I was when I started this project, I realize that won't work and I need to be using the .val(), but not sure how I should be setting this up since I don't know how many rows there will be, or what the names will be, how do I keep everything associated so things don't get mixed up?

The PHP side looks like this before it gets processed.

```
<?
include 'db.php';


$i=0;
    foreach($db->query('SELECT * from navmenu') as $row) {
    $rowarray[$row[0]] = array();
    echo ($i % 2)?'<tr class="odd">':'<tr class="even">';

        print_r("<td width=200>" . $row[2] . "</td>");
        print_r("<input type=\"hidden\" id=\""); 
        $row[2] = str_replace(' ', '_', $row[2]);
        print_r("". $row[2] . "[0]\"  value=\"" . $row[0] . "\">");
        print_r("<td><input type=\"textbox\" id=\"" . $row[2] . "[1]\" size=\"75\" value=\"" . $row[3] . "\"></td>");
        //parent selection
        print_r("<td><select id=\"" . $row[2] . "[2]\">");

        if($row[1] == "0"){
            print_r("<option value=\"0\" selected>No Parent</option>");
        }

    foreach($db->query('SELECT * from navmenu') as $option) {
        print_r("<option value=\"" . $option[0] . "\"");
        if($row[1] == $option[0]){
            print_r(" selected");
        }
        print_r(">" . $option[2] ."</option>");
        }
        // end foreach
        print_r("</select></td>");
        print_r("<td><input type=\"textbox\" id=\"" . $row[2] . "[3]\" size=\"5\" value=\"" . $row[4] . "\"></td>");
        // setup status whether active or not
        print_r("<td><input type=\"hidden\" id=\"" . $row[2] . "[4]\" value=\"INACTIVE\"> "); //set value so it never passes NULL
            if ($row[3] == "ACTIVE"){
            print_r("<input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"" . $row[2] . "[4]\" value=\"ACTIVE\" checked=\"true\"></td></tr>");
            }
            else{
            print_r("<input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"" . $row[2] . "[4]\" value=\"ACTIVE\"></td></tr>");

            }
    print_r("\n");
    $rowarray[$row[0]]= array("id" => "$row[0]", "parentid" => "$row[1]", "name" => "$row[2]", "url" => "$row[3]", "sortorder" => "$row[4]", "status" => "$row[5]", "tooltip" => "$row[6]"); 
    $i++; //increment by one

    }

?>
```

This was what I was trying to use for the JQuery:

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("a[id^=formsubmit]").click(function ( event ) {
            $.post( "functions.php?do=adminmenu", $( "#saveForm" ).serialize() );
            }
            ,function (data) {
                $( ".contentarea2" ).html( data );
            },"html");
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you're asking how to send all form data without knowing ahead of time what that form data is? Like so:

```
$("#form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // abort any pending request
    if (request) {
        request.abort();
    }

    var $form = $(this);
    var $inputs = $form.find("input, select, button, textarea");
    var postData = $form.serialize();
    // note: we disable elements AFTER the form data has been serialized
    $inputs.prop("disabled", true);
    request = $.ajax({
        url: "submit.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: postData
    })
    .done(function(response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        // do something
    })
    .fail(function(jqHXR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.error('Error: ' + textStatus, errorThrown);
    });
});
```

As far as processing it on the PHP end, you should name the fields which might have a variable number of values as an array (using brackets), for example:

```
<input type="text" name="ids[]" />
```

Then you can loop through it and process accordingly.

Comment: Thank you so much! Is there a way to have it return the postData so I can see what is being sent to the next page? I tried looking in the console but it just says "array". Figure maybe just putting it in a <div> area for debugging?

Comment: I got it sending results to a div, but it just says it is an empty array. It didn't seem to find any of the data.

Comment: Yes, you can return it from the PHP file with something like `echo json_encode($_POST);`, then handle it however you want.